Web Speech API and WebView compatibility
I have a website that uses the SpeechSynthesis from the Web Speech API. Now, I need to migrate this site to Android, but the Android WebView doesn't support SpeechSynthesis, while Chrome on Android does.

Is there any way to use the Chrome Android engine in WebView?

I would like to know if there is any community-made alternative WebView that supports the Web Speech API?

Is there any free API similar to the Web Speech API that is compatible with WebView?


Thanks in advance for your help!
I tried Android-AdvancedWebView without success.

No.  WebView doesn't allow you to change the engine, it's a custom chromium app.  You can launch a browser via intent, but what browser is installed may change based on the OEM and the user and may not be Chrome (I personally have firefox as the default browser).
As far as a community supported replacement for WebView-  you really want the massive security risk of including and updating an entire browser within your app?  No, you don't.  If you need speech that badly, write a native app and you can access the built in speech to text functionality.
